# catch2 throws and error when adding a struct

Tags: c++, catch-unit-test, catch2

This is the root of my project. I think I am missing a basic concept because the error occur when I wrap the the `find()` function in a struct.

```
  CMakeLists.txt
  bst.cpp
  bst.hpp
  bst-test.cpp
  catch.hpp
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.4 FATAL_ERROR)

project(bst LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_library(bst bst.cpp)

add_executable(bst-test bst-test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bst-test bst)

enable_testing()

add_test(
         NAME catch_test
         COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:bst-test> --success
         )
```

`bst.cpp`

```
struct Bst {
  int find(int num, int array[]) { return -1; }
};
```

`bst.hpp`

```
struct Bst {
  int find(int num, int array[]);
};
```

`bst-test.cpp`

```
#include "bst.hpp"
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("The number to search is not found in the list", "[notFound]") {
  int array[]{};
  Bst tree;
  REQUIRE(tree.find(1, array) == -1);
}
```

This is the error when trying to compile.

```
CMakeFiles/bst-test.dir/bst-test.cpp.o: In function `____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0()':
bst-test.cpp:(.text+0x2b0b5): undefined reference to `Bst::find(int, int*)'
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
CMakeFiles/bst-test.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target 'bst-test' failed
make[2]: *** [bst-test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/bst-test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bst-test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: It's probably expecting a definition like `int Bst::Find(int num, ...)` instead of this re-declaration of `struct Bst`.

Comment: It should not even compile (not just fail on linking), because you have `Bst` redefinition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are declaring the `Bst` structure again in your .cpp file. The source file should only contain the definition of the methods, not the declaration of the structure.

Changing `bst.cpp` to the following fixes the error:

```
#include "bst.hpp"
int Bst::find(int num, int array[]) { return -1; }
```